# Check if multiple columns exist in a df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering how to properly check if multiple columns exist in a `df`, say if I want to test if both columns `A` and `B` exist in `df`:

```
if `A` in df and `B` in df:
    # some code
```

is there a better way to do this checking? tested with `['A', 'B'] in df`, but failed.

UPDATE

```
 pd.Series(['A', 'B']).isin(df.columns).all()
```

will do the work.

Comment: Specifically, the second answer.

Comment: I respect you guys' decision to delete your answers. +1 respect to you both.